# How to make a valid hmac authentication header

Tags: php, laravel, rest, guzzle

I'm trying to use the combell api to automate my hosting. I need to generate a HMAC authentication header to the API-request. I'm using Guzzle.

My current code with my header generates this error:

> Client error: GET https://api.combell.com/v2/accounts resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "error_code": "authorization_hmac_invalid", "error_text": "The hmac is invalid." }

**My controller**

```
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    protected $api_key;
    protected $api_secret;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api_key = env('API_KEY');
        $this->api_secret = env('API_SECRET');
    }

    protected function hmacHandler() {
        $key = $this->api_key;
        $req_method = 'get';
        $path_query = 'https://api.combell.com/';
        $timestamp = time();
        $nonce = substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 8);
        $content = '';

        $valueToSign = $this->api_key
            . $req_method
            . urlencode($path_query)
            . $timestamp
            . $nonce
            . $content;

        $signedValue = hash_hmac('sha256', $valueToSign, $this->api_secret, true);

        $signature = base64_encode($signedValue);

        return sprintf('hmac %s:%s:%s:%s', $this->api_key, $signature, $nonce, $timestamp);
    }

    public function index() {

        dd($this->getTestData());
    }

    public function getTestData() {
        $client = new Client();
        $uri = 'https://api.combell.com/v2/accounts';
        $header = ['headers' => ['Authorization' => $this->hmacHandler()]];
        $res = $client->get($uri, $header);
        return json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if my hmac function is incorrect or if i'm using the Guzzle Authorization header in the wrong way, any tips?

[Combell API documentation](https://api.combell.com/v2/documentation#section/Authentication/Steps-to-generate-the-HMAC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the response, the Authorization header is fine (syntax to add the header looks good), but the value is incorrect.

The doc states that the path has to be relative. Try to replace

`$path_query = 'https://api.combell.com/';`

with

`$path_query = '/v2/accounts';` (or `/accounts`, the doc isn't clear).

The content shouldn't be necessary because the body is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your header is missing information.

The signingString identifies parts used in the encoding and must also be contained in the header.

Example:

```
$date = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
$signingString = "Date: $date";
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signingString, $secret, true));
$authorization = "hmac username=\"$user\", algorithm=\"hmac-sha1\", headers=\"Date\", signature=\"$signature\"";

$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Date' => $date,
        'Authorization' => $authorization,
        'Content-MD5' => $bodyHash ];

$options = [
   'headers' => $header,
   'json' => $body];
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, $options);
```

In this example, the '***Date***' field is passed in the header with a value,  used in the encoding (signingString) with the secret and the '***Authorization***' header identifies which fields to grab within the '***headers***' subfield as part of the decoding.